# Cuando request.getRequestDispatcher se redirige a un doGet o a un doPost

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Estimado Luiggi tengo una duda enorme.

Programo con Servlets y me di con la siguiente sorpresa:

Envío datos por submit a un servlet_1, entonces lo captura un doPost (comprendido!)

desde este servlet_1-->doPost hago un request.getRequestDispatcher(servlet_2).forward(request, response);
Entonces...sí estoy redireccionando con request.getRequestDispatcher... por qué lo captura el doPost (del servlet_2) y no el doGet.

Siempre asumí que un request.getRequestDispatcher envía datos de tipo GET.

Ayúdame a compreder esto.

Answer (score 1):

Esta llamando al `doPost` por que la primera solicitud llamo al metodo `post` cuando se ejecuto el **submit**  lo que hace *request.getRequestDispatcher*  es redirigir la peticion no realizar otra como esta fue realizada por **POST** continuara de esta manera.

si lo que quiere es que al ejecutar el `request.getRequestDispatcher` ingrese al metodo *GET* debe ejecutarla asi desde la primera peticion.

NOTA: solo aceptara respuesta de Luiggi?, si es así lo siento

Comment: Excelente theboshy... era justo lo que pensaba... solo que teóricamente no me quedaba claro... y en efecto hice dicha pregunta porque desde un principio con doPost todo siempre iba a doPost pero cuando hice el mismo proceso desde un principio por doGet... todo iba a doGet... muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

revisa el submit, a que metodo direcciona, si ingresa al post pero quieres que siempre ingrese al get, ya que en el post no tienes nada, entonces en el dopost, agregas la sentencia doGet(Request,Response);

Comment: En efecto Nestor... justo hago eso... pero no me quedaba claro por qué doPost a doPost y en efecto me lo aclaró theboshy... los eventos desde un principio al pasar por varios servlets respetan la jerarquía es decir... redireccionan... todo claro... muchas gracias